# How to know storage engine used of a database?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

Previously, on every database created, I use:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost';
```

and then use the database without thinking about MyISAM or InnoDB

How to know storage engine used of a database?

Answer (score 17):

You can check per-table like this:

```
USE <database>;
SHOW TABLE STATUS\G
```

you'll get an output along these lines:

```
root@localhost/database> show table status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: tablename
         Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Fixed
           Rows: 101
 Avg_row_length: 70
    Data_length: 7070
Max_data_length: 19703248369745919
   Index_length: 2048
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 1004
    Create_time: 2009-12-07 20:15:53
    Update_time: 2010-11-10 21:55:01
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```

Comment: any way you know of to do all tables in a DB (besides writing a script to `SHOW TABLE` for each table in the DB)?

Comment: @voretaq7 the "SHOW TABLE STATUS" does show you all tables by default.

Comment: cool -- I'm a postgres guy so all this MySQL and multiple storage engines stuff is strange to me :-)

Answer (score 6):

This query lists all InnoDB tables and their databases in MySQL:

```
SELECT table_name, table_schema 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE engine = 'InnoDB';
```

You can also list all tables and their storage engines:

```
SELECT table_name, table_schema, engine
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: I tried the second query - I get the error: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'information_scheme.tables' doesn't exist`  (on MySQL 5.6.37)

Answer (score 5):

Use the 'show engine' command to view the active default engine

Add default-storage-engine=InnoDB in [mysqld] section of the my.cnf file for the default engine to be active.

Use the 'show create table table_name' command to view default engine in the table.

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE` gives me ERROR 1064 (42000).

Comment: ```show engines;```

Answer (score 1):

To get engine name for a specific table

```
use <database_name>
show table status like '<table_name>';
```

To change engine

```
alter table <table_name> engine <engine_name>;
```